# Linux configuration data: standard way of storing application settings?

Tags: linux, architecture, application-settings

I am currently working on a configuration application for an embedded device and was wondering if there is a standard and accepted way of keeping application settings in Linux, something analogous to the Registry system in Windows.

GNOME seems to have a `gnome-settings` system that some graphical applications use, but I am going to be working on a headless, embedded device. The best advice I could find so far seems to be that I should just keep it under `/etc`.

Is there a universally accepted way of keeping app/user settings in Linux or is it simply a case of keeping it in a file under `/etc`?

Thanks.

Comment: `/etc` is okay, please don't mimic the Windows registry, please!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, global settings are in `/etc`, and per-user settings would be in a `.file` or `.directory` under the user's home directory. So you have (from memory), `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` for bash.

Oh, and not all applications put their configuration under `/etc`. That's usually for applications that need some level of system management, as opposed to purely user applications like a word processor or game.